# How to enforce bundle install location

Tags: ruby, bundler

I come from a Python and JavaScript background.

When developing a JavaScript project, dependencies are installed in a `node_modules` directory in the project root.

When developing Python project, typically virtualenvwrapper is used. In this case dependencies are installed in a virtual environment, which is located in `~/.virtualenvs/<project_name>` by default.

Now I need to use a ruby tool for a project. The tool that appears to be the most promising for a similar setup as described above, is bundler.

However, the default installation location for bundler is system-wide. I consider this to be harmful.

For one of my systems, it will prompt for a password, at which point I can still abort.

However, for my other system I can write into the global ruby installation. I'm using a homebrew installed ruby here. Bundle will just install dependencies globally.

I know I can specify the installation location by adding `--path`, but this is easy to forget.

One way to enforce an installation path is by committing `.bundle/config`. It would just have to contain this:

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: "."
```

However, some googling around shows that it's not adviced to commit this file.

What is the recommended way to prevent accidental global installations using bundler?

Comment: why don't you try rvm gemsets https://rvm.io/gemsets ?

Answer (score 0):

Who's to say it will be accidental? It really depends on what context you're talking about here. I have my Ruby set up so that `bundle install` works without requiring `sudo`, it's all done through [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) automatically. The same is true with [`rvm`](https://rvm.io) if done as a user-level install.

When it comes to deploying apps and you want to make sure it's deployed correctly, that's where tools like [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com) come into play: Create a deployment script that will apply the correct procedure every time.

Checking in a `.bundle/config` is really rude from a dev perspective, just like checking in any other user-specific preferences you might have. It causes no end of conflict with other team members.